# Dimension $\mathrm{Hom}(a,b)$ for finite group representations.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}_4 \ltimes_\phi \mathbb{Z}_{35}$ be a semidirect product of groups. $\phi:x \mapsto x^{22}$. Let also $C_\epsilon$ and $C_\delta$ be complex irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$ ($\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are primitive roots).

I need to calculate dimensions of $\mathrm{Hom}(Ind_{\mathbb{Z}_{35}}^G C_\delta, Ind_{\mathbb{Z}_{35}}^G C_\delta)$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(Ind_{\mathbb{Z}_{4}}^G C_\epsilon, Ind_{\mathbb{Z}_{35}}^G C_\delta)$. Any hints how I can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\phi:x\mapsto x^{22}$?

Comment: @anon $\phi$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$. $\mathbb{Z}_4 $ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$ by powers of $\phi$.

Comment: Seems like $\phi^4\neq \mathrm{id}$?

Comment: use Mackey's induced character formula. Do you know the cosets of $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\mathbb Z_{35}$ in the semidirect product?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг So I can write down matrix representations using induced character formula and what should I do next?

Comment: @GlebChili The quantity $Hom(Ind_{\mathbb Z_{35}}^G C_\delta, Ind_{\mathbb Z_{35}}^G C_{\delta})$ is the inner product of the characters. Using the matrix representation, find the value of the characters at all the coset representatives, and then use the definition of the inner product.